# Removing old versions of DLL from server

Tags: c#, .net, gac

I have a problem where I have installed a DLL on a server into the GAC.

When I try and uninstall it using the windows installer it still remains in the GAC.

Is there anyway of removing this DLL completely from the GAC safely without affecting parts of the server/system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're sure the DLL is no longer being used, it should be safe to remove it using `gacutil`. Note that `gacutil` is part of the .NET SDK, rather than the base runtime.